# PDO::FETCH_ASSOC not fetching everything

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I have this function:

```
function get_following($user_id) {
 global $conn;
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM following WHERE `follower_id`=:user");
 $stmt->bindParam(':user', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt->execute();
 $following =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 return $following;
}
```

The `following` table looks like this:

```
|user_id|follower_id|
|   2   |     5     |
|   3   |     5     |
|   4   |     5     |
```

Now the problem is when I actually call the function it only selects one of the rows from the table, where my follower_id = 5.

Comment: Hint: reading a manual page for the function often helps

Answer (score 6):

$following will have to be an array of rows. You are actually only fetching the first row. Fetch it using [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), like this:

```
$following = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Worked perfectly!